# Share text on facebook wall in iphone is not working?

Tags: ios

I want to share text directly in iphone . I have implemented the following code on button click

[image]

```
    login authentication has to be successfully done but when i click the post button it show some error .
```

i have implemented following error line
[image] 
[image]

```
**I m using facebook direct api for this Facebook API**
```

Comment: What is "fbGraph"? Can you show the code for where that comes from?

Comment: fbGraph is nothing but facebook Graph api class obj

Comment: fbGraph = [[FbGraph alloc] initWithFbClientID:client_id];

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted, but I also can't tell where the error is happening. Can you run "bt" in the debugger when it crashes and post it here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure,but I think that parser should have some delegate(look in SBJson class)
e.g parserDidfinishParsing

It looks like now your are telling to the  parser "start parse" and releasing it before it have finished